# Linker cannot find qwebp lib - static Qt5.3.2 compilation

Tags: c++, linux, qt, static, qt5

I'm trying to compile Qt 5.3.2 library statically on `Linux 3.2.0-4-amd64` with `g++ 4.7.2-5`. I used this command to configure compilation and installation makefiles:

```
configure -prefix /usr/local/Qt5-static -debug -opensource -platform linux-g++ -opengl desktop -static -nomake examples -nomake tests -qt-zlib -qt-libpng -qt-libjpeg -qt-freetype -qt-harfbuzz -qt-pcre -qt-xkbcommon -qt-xcb
```

Everything in this step have been done correctly. Secondly I ran:

```
make
```

and

```
make install
```

In the last step I received this error:

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lqwebp
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I downloaded source code from https://git.gitorious.org/qt/qt5.git and used commit assigned to `v5.3.2` git tag.

Answer (score 0):

Find where you have such library libqwebp and then add this dir -Ldir_path to compilation options.

Comment: It's a Qt's library - I cannot have it due to the fact that it should be compiled and linked in this compilation. I have WebP library (with development files), but Qt needs QWebP.

Comment: Do you have such file ./qtimageformats/plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.a after compilation?

Comment: No, I haven't, but I have libqwebp.prl.

Comment: Ok, then pls show me what you have in this file libqwebp.prl. Additionally grep make output by libqwebp.a. You should get:
rm -f libqwebp.a
ar cqs libqwebp.a .obj/main.o .obj/qwebphandler.o......(long output)
rm -f ../../../../plugins/imageformats/libqwebp.a
mv -f libqwebp.a ../../../../plugins/imageformats/
if this is compiled fine or info about potential errors/warnings. The last thing which I have in mind is that you have to use QT_PLUGIN to include this imageformat.

Comment: libqwebp.prl: http://pastebin.com/qcDSQGpQ grep from make install: http://pastebin.com/JBqTakZF I do not need WebP format so maybe I will omit this plugin.